# How to pass a column name using string_split - ms sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to pass column names using a string split because I need the values from that table to join with another table.

I've already achieved this in Postgresql where I get the values from these columns:

```
   SELECT unnest(array["column_name1","column_name2","column_name3" AS "amount"
   FROM table1
```

The unnest in combination with the quotes around the column names returns an array to a set of row for every value.

```
Amount
307579.00
25579.00
212871.00
```

Now I want to do the same in MS Server:

```
   DECLARE @amount NVARCHAR(50) = 'column_name1/column_name2/column_name3'
   SELECT "value" from string_split(@amount,'/')
```

But this only gives me the literal string:

```
Amount
column_name1
column_name2
column_name3
```

I've been trying and searching how to pass an elemant that will read as a column name and shows the values in one column like the first example, maybe I shouldn't use the string splitter etc. Kinda stuck on this..

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with Postgresql  what does the `unnest(array` do? Can you provide example data and desired results?

Comment: `string_split` starts at SqlServer 2016, you should use some function like https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/3270427.

Comment: Yes, so I thought, but I've been using string_split in SqlServer 2014 and works just fine when I actually need the literal string.

Comment: Then someone has added a function with this name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL to implement your logic, by constructing a whole new SELECT query.

For example:

```
DECLARE @CMD nvarchar(max), @amount NVARCHAR(50) = 'column_name1/column_name2/column_name3'
SELECT @CMD = ISNULL(@CMD + ', ', N'SELECT ') + QUOTENAME([value])
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@amount,'/')
SET @CMD = @CMD + N' FROM table1'
PRINT @CMD
EXEC(@CMD)
```

Its output would be:

```
SELECT [column_name1], [column_name2], [column_name3] FROM table1
```

In order to get all the values under a single column, you'll need to "UnPivot" the data. There are two main ways to do so. One is by a standard UNPIVOT command, like so:

```
DECLARE @CMD nvarchar(max), @amount NVARCHAR(50) = 'column_name1/column_name2/column_name3'
SELECT @CMD = ISNULL(@CMD + ', ', N'SELECT unpvt.* FROM table1 UNPIVOT (amount FOR amounttype IN ( ') + QUOTENAME([value])
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@amount,'/')
SET @CMD = @CMD + N' ) AS unpvt'
PRINT @CMD
EXEC(@CMD)
```

Its output would be:

```
SELECT unpvt.* FROM table1 UNPIVOT (amount FOR amounttype IN ( [column_name1], [column_name2], [column_name3]) AS unpvt
```

Another way is to use CROSS APPLY with a Values Constructor, like this:

```
DECLARE @CMD nvarchar(max), @amount NVARCHAR(50) = 'column_name1/column_name2/column_name3'
SELECT @CMD = ISNULL(@CMD + '), (', N'SELECT v.amount FROM table1 CROSS APPLY(VALUES(') + QUOTENAME([value])
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@amount,'/')
SET @CMD = @CMD + N')) AS v(amount)'
PRINT @CMD
EXEC(@CMD)
```

Its output would be:

```
SELECT v.amount FROM table1 CROSS APPLY(VALUES([column_name1]), ([column_name2]), ([column_name3])) AS v(amount)
```

Comment: This actually gives me the values, but in separate columns. Is it possible to have one column e.g. 'amount' with the values stored there?

Comment: Seems I misunderstood your requirements. Sure, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I used the CROSS APPLY and got my desired result. Thanks!

Comment: Pleasure @MarG :)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t (id int, mytext varchar(500));
insert into t values (1, 'column_name1/column_name2/column_name3');

select id, value as amount
from   t
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(mytext, '/');
```

> ```
> id | amount      
> -: | :-----------
>  1 | column_name1
>  1 | column_name2
>  1 | column_name3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3aa00c645c92ab541a70952795f60f70)*